# Trying to add the Aurealia-Authentication to the skeleton-typescript template

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I am trying to add the `aurelia-authentication` plugin to this template [skeleton-navigation](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript) using `TypeScript` but ended up in errors. The `aurelia-authentication` plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/SpoonX/aurelia-authentication)

Either I am doing something wrong by not following the `aurelia-authentication` documentation correct or something is missing in the documentation.

I have tried to integrate twice but ended up with errors when executing the `gulp watch`. Can someone figure out what is missing by looking at the screenshot [here](http://screencast.com/t/VW8TSp6zI7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to solve this issue by installing the `aurelia-api` **first**, then  `aurealia-authentication` by following their installation document which is quite easy to understand. Here are the links to both the documentations.

1. https://aurelia-api.spoonx.org/installation.html
2. https://aurelia-authentication.spoonx.org/installation.html